# ¿Cómo sumar todos los valores de un día de durante una semana?

Tags: mysql, sql, date, mysql-workbench

Tengo una tabla la cual contiene una columna llamada `Fecha` de tipo Date y una columna llamada `Cantidad` de tipo Integer.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Necesito Sumar todos los valores de la columna `Cantidad` diariamente en una semana, por ejemplo:

La semana esta comprendida entre el día 4 de noviembre y el 11 de noviembre, necesito sumar todas las "Cantidades" del día 4 de noviembre que seria 35, después las del día 5, 6, 7, 8 de noviembre que seria 0 (Dado que no hay registros entre el 5 y el 8), después del día 9 que seria 10, posteriormente el día 10 que seria 18.

El resultado seria algo similar a:

```
 Fecha        CantidadDiaria
 2017-11-04         35
 2017-11-09         10
 2017-11-10         18
```

Espero puedan ayudarme..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

la solución seria agruparlos por la fecha y una vez agrupados sumar su cantidad la consulta seria la siguiente:

```
    SELECT Fecha, SUM(CantidadDiaria) FROM calendario GROUP BY Fecha
```

Saludos.

Comment: Gracias lo pude resolver como lo mencionaste..